# Setting up spark cluster on Virtual Machines

Tags: apache-spark

I installed 2 vm machines and also enabled port forwarding so I can ssh from host to guests machines. I started spark standalone Master on host machine, my question is how to set up the 2 vm machines so I can use them as standalone Workers? 
(FYI: VM network adapter is attached to NAT.)

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

**On Worker nodes(vm machines)**

- Use two network adapters: NAT(for internet), Host-Only(to access
  resources). 
  See [how to setup host-only on vm](http://christophermaier.name/2010/09/01/host-only-networking-with-virtualbox/)
- Setup vm machines with same user as host machine.

**On Master node(Host)**

- Add this entry, SPARK_MASTER_HOST={IP ADDRESS} in the
  conf/spark-env.sh to bind spark master to host ip address.
- Add ip addresses of worker nodes(vm machines) to conf/slaves
- Configure Master to passwordlessly ssh into Workers:

  ```
  ssh-keygen
  .ssh/ssh-copy-id -i ./id_rsa.pub {Worker IP Address}
  ```
- Start spark cluster: `./sbin/start-all.sh`

Comment: Can you explain a bit the point 3 for master node? where should we put those commands

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/